# Add Action column to Data Grid to Edit / Delete line

Tags: grid, outsystems, lowcode

[image: I want to add a column at the end of this grid so it displays a menu or shows the options so i can edit that line or delete it]
I want to add a column at the end of this grid so it displays a menu or shows the options so i can edit that line or delete it
But
[image: In outsystems it looks like this]
In outsystems it looks like this]
So I need to add the action column or make a new grid?
I tried adding a action column but it only gave me errors

Also, is there a way to hide the id column? I tried hiding it on the get aggregate but it doesn't seems to work

Please help, Im kind of new using this program